# Default return value for a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I'm new to SQL Server. Currently I'm working on an existing source code and I have some unclear point the stored procedure

For examples:

**My_Stored_Procedure_1**

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[My_Stored_Procedure_1]
    @ID INT,
    @DATE DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE query...
    PRINT 'ID is ' + CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10))
END
```

**My_Stored_Procedure_2**

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[My_Stored_Procedure_2]
   @RESULT INT
AS
BEGIN
   EXEC @RESULT = My_Stored_Procedure_1 // Unclear point
END
```

My question is that, I don't see any return value from the `My_Stored_Procedure_1`, so what will be returned to `@RESULT` variable? Maybe a default returned value of the executed stored procedure?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In SP 2 just add `SELECT @RESULT` below `EXEC @RESULT = My_Stored_Procedure_1` and see what get's returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Result will have default value that was passed while executing the Stored Procedure My_Stored_Procedure_2.

The statement `EXEC @RESULT = My_Stored_Procedure_1` will execute with error and terminate the execution of My_Stored_Procedure_2 because you have not passing two input parameter to My_Stored_Procedure_1 sp while calling this.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a stored procedure is dependent on whether or not the statements in that procedure executed successfully. For example, if your `UPDATE` statement failed due to a constraint error, `@RESULT` would be set to `-6`. If it runs successfully with no error, it would normally be `0`. See the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #testTable (Value INT, CHECK (Value > 5));
INSERT #testTable VALUES (6);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #testProc AS
UPDATE #testTable SET Value = 2;
GO
DECLARE @ret INT;
EXEC @ret = #testProc;
PRINT @ret; -- “-6”
DROP PROCEDURE #testProc;
DROP TABLE #testTable;
GO
```

Note that you never make an attempt to observe the value of `@RESULT`. Since `@RESULT` is not an `OUTPUT` parameter, the caller of `"dbo"."My_Stored_Procedure_2"` will not see the return value of `"dbo"."My_Stored_Procedure_1"`. It looks like you are ignoring the return value. If you could alter your example to show how you are consuming the return value, that can help us understand your question and provide better advice.